# CSS how to refer to last div within multiple divs

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="test">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="pure-g">
                <div class="pure-u-1-4">
                    <div class="spec__test">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pure-u-1-4">
                    <div class="spec__test">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pure-u-1-4">
                    <div class="spec__test">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pure-u-1-4">
                    <div class="spec__test">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I possibly refer to ONLY the last `spec__test` div using CSS?

Answer (score 2):

use :last-child

see: see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

```css
.pure-g .pure-u-1-4:last-child .spec__test{
  background-color:red;  
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="pure-g">
                <div class="pure-u-1-4">
                    <div class="spec__test">123
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pure-u-1-4">
                    <div class="spec__test">123
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pure-u-1-4">
                    <div class="spec__test">123
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pure-u-1-4">
                    <div class="spec__test">123
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is right, but you would still need to add the `.spec-test` at the end for safety (in case there will be more content, which is the reason for the nested div I presume)

Comment: @FalcoB yeah this worked, ty :) i'll accept as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

[:last-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-of-type/)

```css
.pure-g .pure-u-1-4:last-of-type {
   background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="pure-g">
                <div class="pure-u-1-4">
                    <div class="spec__test">123
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pure-u-1-4">
                    <div class="spec__test">123
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pure-u-1-4">
                    <div class="spec__test">123
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pure-u-1-4">
                    <div class="spec__test">123
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `:last-child` is more appropriate here.